# Dummy Payment Method

Tags: checkout, payment-methods

I am trying to create a Payment Method in Magento for Internal Use. Basically it is to track inventory for company expenses for products removed from the inventory internally.

Can a checkout payment method be null or skipped so I can create an order on the frontend without requiring payment? Or should I just use the "Other" payment method without authorization?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I typically use the "Check/Money order" in this scenario - you can change the frontend name to be whatever you prefer. You can always whip something up to hide the option and have it always be selected.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying that one out just now too. I also just saw a Purchase Order option, which works out better because that was something I would have needed to add manually. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to limit payment methods by customer group, that way your internal users get assigned to a specific customer group that is allowed to use that payment method. There are a number of options available if you Google.

Comment: Interesting approach, I didn't know payment methods could be assigned to groups. This will end up being it's own store scope anyway, as our backend handles orders different based on the store.

Comment: I was going to mention that if you were dealing with multiple sites, that would work as well. I think my approach would probably be more useful for store owners with just a single site. It would require a module (whether third party or custom), however.

Comment: Ah ok, so that functionality isn't available in the core?

Comment: No, but it's a relatively basic module.